# Tomcat 8.5 mapping ldap groups to security roles does not work

Tags: tomcat, ldap, realm, web.xml

I'm trying to map `security-roles` of an application to ldap groups in a tomcat 8.5.13. To test this, I'm trying the example protected tomcat app.
From what I've found, I have to add a block like this to the WEB-INF/web.xml of the application:

```
<!-- Security roles referenced by this web application -->
<security-role>
  <role-name>role1</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
  <role-name>tomcat</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role-ref>
    <role-name>CN=LDAP_GROUP,OU=Groups,DC=<sub_dc>,DC=<dc>,DC=com</role-name>
    <role-link>tomcat</role-link>
</security-role-ref>
```

`tomcat` and `role1` are configured as roles in a `auth-constraint` for the example app.

This is my JNDI config in `$TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server.xml`:

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
           resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm"
         connectionURL="ldap://<ldap_host>:3268"
         connectionName="<ldap_bind_dn>"
         connectionPassword="<ldap_pw>"
         connectionTimeout="3000"
         referrals="follow"
         userBase="DC=<sub_dc>,DC=<dc>,DC=com"
         userSubtree="true"
         userSearch="(sAMAccountName={0})"
         userRoleName="memberOf"
         roleBase="DC=<sub_dc>,DC=<dc>,DC=com"
         roleSubtree="true"
         roleSearch="(uniqueMember={0})"
         roleName="cn"
         roleNested="true"
    />
</Realm>
```

I see that all the ldap groups of the user including LDAP_GROUP mentioned in the `security-role-ref` above are found according to the log. However it seems the role reference is not used. Trying `http://<server>:8080/examples/jsp/security/protected/index.jsp` gives:

```
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke  Calling authenticate()
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator.doAuthenticate Restore request from session 'BB74A040FCCEEEDC150EC5671B6BF7B6'
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.register Authenticated 'ldap_user' with type 'FORM'
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.register Session ID changed on authentication from [BB74A040FCCEEEDC150EC5671B6BF7B6] to [A5735CBE706B62943EB9B29899C0CCCD]
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator.doAuthenticate Proceed to restored request
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke  Calling accessControl()
org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.hasResourcePermission   Checking roles GenericPrincipal[ldap_user(CN=LDAP_GROUP,OU=Groups,DC=<sub_dc>,DC=<dc>,DC=com,<many_more_ldap_group_DNs>,)]
org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.hasRole Username ldap_user does NOT have role tomcat
org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.hasResourcePermission No role found:  tomcat
org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.hasRole Username ldap_user does NOT have role role1
org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.hasResourcePermission No role found:  role1
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke  Failed accessControl() test
```

I've tried defining and removing `<role rolename="tomcat"/>` in `$TOMCAT_HOME/conf/tomcat-users.xml` as well as defining the LDAP_GROUP without the distinguished name in the `security-role-ref` but that does not make a difference.

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.